# upload a video and change src attr of an existing video

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video

upload a video - works fine
the new video is in a target folder and it plays well using its url
problem - I want to change the `src` of an existing video (`#bvid`) to the new uploaded video and getting error in console - as the video does not exist

```
<video id='bvid' controls poster='ph/imgt.jpg' src='ph/vid.mp4'></video>  
<input type='file' id='inpfilevid' accept='video/mp4'>
```

**js**

```
$('#inpfilevid').on('change', function(){
    ...
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); // vid/01.mp4 - it's ok
            $('#bvid').attr('src', data); // error line
        }
    });
});
```

**console error**
GET https://example.com/vid/01.mp4 412

Comment: Your original src starts with `ph` but your new src starts with `vid`. Doesn't look right.

Comment: @wazz - yes, the first path is a placeholder video and it plays without problem. The second path is a new path - of the uploaded video

Comment: Access error. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412

Comment: @wazz - permissions of that folder is `0755` - like any other - and all files are accessible using their url. The video is not accessible only using the above `ajax` code